# Lower Bound of a Curve

Tags: r, algorithm, math, computational-geometry

I have a curve likes the following:

[image]

As can be seen, there are two upper bound and lower bound curves on the above (see the following image for the approx visualization!):

[image]

I have tried to find the lower bound by the following code:

```
lower_bound = rbind()
for(i in 2:(length(data[,1])-1))
{
    if(data[i,2] < data[i+1,2] && data[i,2] < data[i-1,2])
    {
        lower_bound = rbind2(lower_bound, c(data[i,1], data[i,2]))
    }    
}
```

But, the problem is there are some local minima in the middle, so the result is not what I've expected (as follow).

[image]

Hence the question is *how can I find the lower bound of such a curve in R*? Is there any known algorithm to find the lower bound?

About the minimal reproducible example, I've included 500 of data (to make sense) in the following:

```
structure(c(3.54246575342466, 5.75616438356164, 6.54246575342466, 
9.73424657534247, 7.75616438356164, 9.75616438356164, 1.41917808219178, 
2.75342465753425, 3.16986301369863, 2.27123287671233, 3.74520547945205, 
5.74520547945205, 4.29315068493151, 3.37260273972603, 8.37534246575343, 
3.33698630136986, 5.04657534246575, 6.92328767123288, 1.33972602739726, 
6.34246575342466, 26.358904109589, 2.34794520547945, 4.35068493150685, 
7.35342465753425, 27.3671232876712, 1.15068493150685, 2.14794520547945, 
4.15342465753425, 6.15342465753425, 9.15616438356164, 19.1616438356164, 
29.1698630136986, 2.58904109589041, 4.5972602739726, 9.6, 29.613698630137, 
3.10684931506849, 8.11780821917808, 3.35068493150685, 8.37260273972603, 
5.11506849315068, 28.1315068493151, 5.36986301369863, 28.386301369863, 
4.87945205479452, 4.46027397260274, 5.35616438356164, 25.3698630136986, 
25.8684931506849, 5.85479452054795, 1.85205479452055, 4.37260273972603, 
6.37260273972603, 9.37534246575343, 19.3835616438356, 29.3890410958904, 
18.3808219178082, 1.36986301369863, 8.37534246575343, 3.37260273972603, 
5.85479452054795, 28.3890410958904, 2.87671232876712, 4.87945205479452, 
7.37808219178082, 8.17260273972603, 28.186301369863, 4.29315068493151, 
6.96164383561644, 26.3479452054795, 7.96438356164384, 1.53972602739726, 
1.58630136986301, 5.04657534246575, 16.6356164383562, 18.4684931506849, 
25.0602739726027, 15.6493150684932, 24.8547945205479, 25.3506849315068, 
26.1068493150685, 16.0547945205479, 2.16712328767123, 19.2657534246575, 
20.6849315068493, 1.04383561643836, 3.04383561643836, 23.0575342465753, 
3.29315068493151, 4.13150684931507, 2.04383561643836, 22.0575342465753, 
22.8904109589041, 2.87671232876712, 5.54246575342466, 25.5561643835616, 
1.04931506849315, 6.05205479452055, 26.0657534246575, 2.09041095890411, 
7.09315068493151, 27.1068493150685, 2.09041095890411, 4.09315068493151, 
6.09315068493151, 9.0958904109589, 19.1013698630137, 29.1095890410959, 
1.83287671232877, 1.42739726027397, 3.43013698630137, 9.3041095890411, 
2.72328767123288, 8.58082191780822, 2.8958904109589, 4.92054794520548, 
9.92328767123288, 6.92054794520548, 19.9315068493151, 29.9369863013699, 
20.9315068493151, 2.25205479452055, 22.2657534246575, 3.40821917808219, 
23.4219178082192, 8.21095890410959, 3.20821917808219, 5.20821917808219, 
18.8027397260274, 19.8054794520548, 21.7232876712329, 2.25205479452055, 
22.8054794520548, 24.4301369863014, 4.41643835616438, 25.2684931506849, 
5.25479452054795, 6.33698630136986, 26.3506849315068, 2.87671232876712, 
4.29315068493151, 2.78630136986301, 1.2958904109589, 1.75890410958904, 
2.29041095890411, 7.2958904109589, 3.44657534246575, 4.5041095890411, 
9.73424657534247, 8.21643835616438, 6.29315068493151, 7.50684931506849, 
3.75616438356164, 7.96438356164384, 9.96438356164384, 29.9780821917808, 
17.3452054794521, 26.8547945205479, 5.5041095890411, 7.17260273972603, 
6.13150684931507, 3.62739726027397, 5.79452054794521, 7.7972602739726, 
5.75616438356164, 3.09041095890411, 8.0958904109589, 9.63013698630137, 
4.93424657534247, 6.93424657534247, 9.93698630136986, 19.9452054794521, 
6.42191780821918, 8.96438356164384, 28.9780821917808, 15.7643835616438, 
18.7205479452055, 1.20547945205479, 4.16986301369863, 24.1835616438356, 
25.2520547945205, 26.3095890410959, 9.61917808219178, 12.3424657534247, 
14.2986301369863, 23.7698630136986, 3.71232876712329, 8.71506849315069, 
3.58082191780822, 1.25205479452055, 5.96164383561644, 3.46027397260274, 
8.46301369863014, 7.88219178082192, 5.54246575342466, 6.46027397260274, 
4.79452054794521, 3.20821917808219, 15.5506849315068, 9.5972602739726, 
20.6, 2.09041095890411, 1.87671232876712, 22.2191780821918, 5.67397260273973, 
25.7260273972603, 26.9753424657534, 7.2958904109589, 27.5205479452055, 
8.17260273972603, 28.3095890410959, 29.2246575342466, 3.87945205479452, 
9.13424657534247, 5.84109589041096, 3.96164383561644, 4.54246575342466, 
9.92602739726027, 29.9397260273973, 16.1397260273973, 16.1780821917808, 
16.1397260273973, 18.7643835616438, 18.7643835616438, 20.2191780821918, 
20.6383561643836, 20.8904109589041, 1.16712328767123, 21.2657534246575, 
1.33424657534247, 2.04383561643836, 2.20547945205479, 4.75616438356164, 
2.92054794520548, 23.2219178082192, 4.09315068493151, 4.24931506849315, 
5.13150684931507, 5.96164383561644, 6.20821917808219, 27.3917808219178, 
29.2246575342466, 9.75890410958904, 8.75890410958904, 28.2712328767123, 
8.42465753424658, 28.4383561643836, 2.37260273972603, 4.37534246575343, 
4.75616438356164, 1.67123287671233, 3.96164383561644, 2.37260273972603, 
5.04657534246575, 2.25205479452055, 5.62739726027397, 4.29315068493151, 
1.29041095890411, 3.5041095890411, 5.5041095890411, 5.09315068493151, 
3.83561643835616, 8.46301369863014, 3.42191780821918, 1.33424657534247, 
4.5041095890411, 4.79452054794521, 6.37534246575343, 7.21095890410959, 
9.37808219178082, 29.3534246575342, 3.54246575342466, 28.6904109589041, 
8.2958904109589, 8.54246575342466, 4.62739726027397, 12.4082191780822, 
19.4712328767123, 20.972602739726, 3.67397260273973, 4.42191780821918, 
4.46027397260274, 25.3890410958904, 5.87945205479452, 25.8931506849315, 
2.20547945205479, 27.2246575342466, 7.88219178082192, 1.43561643835616, 
2.43561643835616, 4.46027397260274, 6.46027397260274, 9.46301369863014, 
19.4712328767123, 29.4767123287671, 2.45753424657534, 9.63013698630137, 
7.88219178082192, 23.641095890411, 5.13150684931507, 6.46027397260274, 
9.7972602739726, 29.8109589041096, 3.21095890410959, 8.21643835616438, 
4.92328767123288, 3.25479452054795, 2.62465753424658, 3.71232876712329, 
5.75616438356164, 25.7698630136986, 6.20821917808219, 1.20547945205479, 
4.96164383561644, 2.09041095890411, 4.13150684931507, 2.45753424657534, 
27.4767123287671, 7.46301369863014, 3.2, 18.2164383561644, 1.1972602739726, 
5.20821917808219, 8.21095890410959, 28.2246575342466, 19.972602739726, 
7.50684931506849, 9.92602739726027, 3.75616438356164, 1.38904109589041, 
3.39178082191781, 19.4082191780822, 2.04383561643836, 24.0602739726027, 
5.75616438356164, 26.4356164383562, 6.42191780821918, 28.0630136986301, 
8.21095890410959, 18.2164383561644, 6.37534246575343, 3.96164383561644, 
6.87945205479452, 7.75890410958904, 5.54246575342466, 7.75890410958904, 
2.19452054794521, 27.213698630137, 29.227397260274, 8.2, 5.87945205479452, 
1.12876712328767, 3.12876712328767, 7.54520547945206, 2.74246575342466, 
4.74520547945205, 6.74520547945205, 9.74794520547945, 29.7616438356164, 
3.58904109589041, 8.53150684931507, 18.5369863013699, 28.5452054794521, 
4.96164383561644, 19.3479452054795, 1.04657534246575, 21.386301369863, 
3.96164383561644, 5.42191780821918, 3.62739726027397, 7.13150684931507, 
2.54246575342466, 27.5616438356164, 18.0547945205479, 4.16986301369863, 
9.25753424657534, 4.76986301369863, 15.2164383561644, 6.37534246575343, 
8.17808219178082, 3.73424657534247, 1.26849315068493, 6.27123287671233, 
6.2986301369863, 19.3945205479452, 17.1397260273973, 1.20547945205479, 
6.20821917808219, 3.37534246575342, 5.25479452054795, 4.75616438356164, 
6.54246575342466, 3.16986301369863, 2.04383561643836, 4.25479452054795, 
1.04383561643836, 7.71506849315069, 5.09315068493151, 4.42191780821918, 
6.71232876712329, 3.04383561643836, 1.67945205479452, 3.30958904109589, 
3.96164383561644, 2.92054794520548, 7.92602739726027, 27.9397260273973, 
2.83835616438356, 7.46301369863014, 8.21095890410959, 7.23835616438356, 
27.2520547945205, 2.53972602739726, 6.58904109589041, 9.96438356164384, 
29.9780821917808, 16.4301369863014, 18.3671232876712, 19.2657534246575, 
20.386301369863, 2.37534246575342, 6.46027397260274, 26.4739726027397, 
6.62739726027397, 4.75616438356164, 6.71232876712329, 28.8958904109589, 
15.5123287671233, 14.8465753424658, 14.8465753424658, 2.0027397260274, 
3.20821917808219, 3.71232876712329, 1.6958904109589, 2.07671232876712, 
7.75616438356164, 2.88493150684931, 4.29315068493151, 1.84931506849315, 
8.8958904109589, 1.12328767123288, 5.38630136986301, 5.12602739726027, 
8.25205479452055, 3.24931506849315, 1.38904109589041, 5.89315068493151, 
6.60821917808219, 1.5013698630137, 3.46027397260274, 6.5041095890411, 
7.75890410958904, 6.54246575342466, 9.37808219178082, 3.96164383561644, 
5.04657534246575, 7.04657534246575, 8.13424657534247, 6.13150684931507, 
9.37808219178082, 7.96438356164384, 11.0493150684932, 12.213698630137, 
2.12876712328767, 6.67397260273973, 4.46027397260274, 24.4739726027397, 
3.75616438356164, 8.75890410958904, 18.7643835616438, 8.46301369863014, 
5.13150684931507, 9.88219178082192, 9.33150684931507, 5.96164383561644, 
7.25753424657534, 5.62739726027397, 7.50684931506849, 4.84109589041096, 
3.46027397260274, 3.92054794520548, 18.5095890410959, 7.13150684931507, 
8.59178082191781, 3.42191780821918, 6.75616438356164, 4.75616438356164, 
2.95890410958904, 3.96164383561644, 20.4328767123288, 1.41917808219178, 
21.4328767123288, 22.1041095890411, 2.09041095890411, 23.2219178082192, 
3.20821917808219, 3.75616438356164, 24.7698630136986, 25.4739726027397, 
4.46027397260274, 2.75970346198464, 3.45063169924232, 3.64711503029937, 
4.21614538082358, 4.46897200885451, 4.78330432863798, 2.44945159376164, 
3.0246987676982, 3.18637219409113, 2.82704067767991, 3.39633877759394, 
4.01211492772477, 3.58227507536714, 3.26211339894416, 4.58021400951056, 
3.24894671597498, 3.81640051029768, 4.29811641034397, 2.41235239871336, 
4.16381972504066, 4.82320604897032, 2.85924829032196, 3.60102245001335, 
4.38947242891732, 4.83225858506487, 2.32276057802484, 2.77466777269801, 
3.53613679638981, 4.11732178923756, 4.70239811454869, 5.02684596680901, 
4.89394362719873, 2.95858956427959, 3.67972641713649, 4.76329504168897, 
4.91952178329268, 3.16243766754998, 4.53553009720828, 3.25401782240246, 
4.57975033696973, 3.83648225102819, 4.85066377882221, 3.90946630290976, 
4.85924427553214, 3.7665702648057, 3.63632959242775, 3.90561093988307, 
4.82873462476434, 4.25993172383506, 3.47661513525158, 2.08147939877802, 
3.04373161945452, 3.60670989847648, 4.16882946922235, 4.45461902145002, 
4.34162315280691, 4.48802758727908, 1.86206866940942, 4.01581962612883, 
2.69771901556242, 3.47661513525158, 4.29494911958988, 2.50903075277185, 
3.20217588142397, 3.83011128813872, 3.980829920259, 4.28800748360142, 
3.58227507536714, 4.30653857989399, 4.82319396445967, 4.50784277427558, 
1.94072216406505, 1.96202863703256, 3.25200612691594, 4.52865722521467, 
4.48533445537866, 4.26859229653523, 4.53731981080683, 4.27200767176305, 
4.26457120140531, 4.2589693893104, 4.53525135174211, 2.21846989417729, 
4.45880330075475, 4.40569121171677, 1.7068990376281, 2.57392106736465, 
4.31836655689863, 2.66826592342152, 2.96442641830962, 2.16545787147435, 
4.35324929683238, 4.32386522416303, 2.50903075277185, 3.39298854017977, 
4.26232802572813, 1.70955300282675, 3.52741837222827, 4.25907996756536, 
2.18557386001823, 3.77060768900683, 4.26395740412398, 2.18557386001823, 
2.95157192131744, 3.53780855712753, 4.12926524629975, 4.46454130003024, 
4.32641578537161, 2.63737387449928, 2.45327077112083, 3.28325793775465, 
4.41181850146463, 3.01267661647382, 4.30273228804522, 3.0809392572752, 
3.77893332429253, 4.80391883502991, 4.29751273896985, 4.9988952974639, 
4.94101980513708, 4.96053762255352, 2.81894331471379, 4.91003396772332, 
3.27522101695249, 4.87134979305318, 4.55194984744145, 3.20084942592193, 
3.86347792664764, 5.03902446306499, 5.00360541053749, 4.93013307063464, 
2.81894331471379, 4.89111202391337, 4.84484889948005, 3.62226986596664, 
4.83000471370643, 3.87684000847915, 4.16249148956975, 4.82319682171546, 
3.07342513615359, 3.58227507536714, 3.03776390795916, 2.39174353424389, 
2.60441382154721, 2.83511983796416, 4.3776430683761, 3.28927099619789, 
3.65030540624117, 4.78053976420514, 3.98851220598087, 3.84027419541323, 
4.10888701756863, 3.08864056496118, 4.50784277427558, 4.80886282388512, 
4.94393108371142, 5.0798798303101, 4.82563811883379, 3.9468402869224, 
4.35189109140176, 4.11184051977588, 3.35459034230467, 4.02517710657812, 
4.47676297113471, 4.01502608262676, 2.59176865382458, 3.96722952163555, 
4.76721313996148, 3.21864402185455, 3.73613392685585, 4.2411779069777, 
4.43398643591996, 3.61855452792053, 4.10980345553821, 4.31985435471796, 
5.10135192405871, 5.04171773535286, 2.34892141444876, 3.5416097666887, 
4.85054794533227, 4.83022204838818, 4.82316539945316, 4.76579152488111, 
4.70585851301182, 4.77956222001954, 4.54973985879503, 3.38475186086735, 
4.63579216766113, 3.33790973940492, 2.37103458556849, 3.75717008349914, 
2.98272273951349, 4.28337045807013, 4.49267828838454, 3.9573829235615, 
4.19209673281346, 3.74079199043232, 3.20084942592193, 5.10187826143602, 
4.76293750094991, 4.97336905684238, 2.74996824339996, 2.65677488819793, 
4.91172311677223, 3.99307443262087, 4.82526350378577, 4.8268073878022, 
4.3776430683761, 4.83510606972691, 4.54522430364073, 4.85652654574101, 
4.89686171640296, 2.87874743905149, 4.13483923719495, 4.03742401175551, 
3.47139417367879, 3.66246558484484, 4.80424996332984, 4.94121262270349, 
4.53454492449136, 4.53419598722523, 4.53454492449136, 4.47589167424468, 
4.47589167424468, 4.42360799906947, 4.4074923871952, 4.39773506579433, 
2.01907578318878, 4.38322128535129, 1.84538737297096, 2.41830268718988, 
2.23480800909955, 3.16465475329972, 2.52618004042805, 4.56596058005526, 
2.95157192131744, 3.00349899341948, 3.52972300068793, 3.75717008349914, 
3.56654832534446, 4.26829419274457, 4.33246733302122, 4.47209933166968, 
4.07829496689505, 4.54366179335202, 4.02412309850527, 4.29676089988903, 
2.8695390825768, 3.60901246346208, 3.72904913668145, 2.56498963399193, 
3.47139417367879, 2.8695390825768, 3.81640051029768, 2.81894331471379, 
3.98051398879079, 3.58227507536714, 2.38916039360867, 3.31021811457649, 
3.9468402869224, 3.83007753533476, 3.42794910435245, 4.59492002573633, 
3.28024670656985, 2.4097817563527, 3.65030540624117, 3.74079199043232, 
4.17176477555296, 4.35996196359352, 4.73359981456944, 4.90398228783007, 
3.32409784536479, 4.87118581003356, 4.56666593488235, 4.60802805678997, 
3.68916442604293, 5.02118529619339, 4.4514690518147, 4.39455164410878, 
2.80677702722226, 3.05963754502245, 3.07193520904601, 4.2641136733005, 
3.48305015568073, 4.25979660315916, 2.23480800909955, 4.26558395648925, 
3.9282839050028, 1.89269207014021, 2.33130752327983, 3.07193520904601, 
3.62770234943172, 4.18074663670204, 4.4514690518147, 4.34675554764834, 
2.34036194508005, 4.20281875657975, 4.49267828838454, 4.86491005913173, 
3.84127256835413, 4.19209673281346, 4.78844960315538, 4.93234475967529, 
3.20188086629451, 4.5529065893626, 3.7797549774533, 3.21833597902597, 
2.97302436839012, 3.38475186086735, 4.01502608262676, 4.82494685548552, 
4.1309427087262, 2.34892141444876, 3.79122469981557, 2.74996824339996, 
3.52882080169136, 2.90475632846179, 4.83425050183613, 4.41167553240461, 
3.19775298791517, 5.05733248819791, 2.34500731502677, 3.86347792664764, 
4.55194984744145, 4.8536532162969, 4.68580090262939, 3.8560422018531, 
4.80424996332984, 2.83579574924565, 2.43541801827223, 3.26917867887851, 
4.70658092262176, 2.41830268718988, 4.54205071405147, 3.70347651496055, 
4.51179026913548, 3.87139934363606, 4.53702297816656, 4.24040027977525, 
4.74578292053171, 4.17176477555296, 3.15984460601259, 3.9768746297032, 
4.46949323821673, 3.9573829235615, 4.46949323821673, 2.79454182212808, 
4.82981722014996, 4.89700936635987, 4.55003332824908, 4.04744453906246, 
2.31225215646125, 3.17078397447093, 4.42804643606615, 3.02033214617563, 
3.72568245460231, 4.25829574912718, 4.78226928394965, 4.92905316482749, 
3.34086061969711, 4.04183801378363, 4.48319605565641, 4.30085456068988, 
3.79122469981557, 4.45589006029623, 1.70822621819291, 4.63142865759546, 
2.90699979029706, 3.35965176254463, 2.79019595892293, 3.77878982474076, 
2.37522576957373, 4.27154459842833, 4.49758018625893, 2.97721538330697, 
4.15244511731778, 3.73325024745895, 5.10139379386631, 4.17176477555296, 
4.54618813621284, 3.39248194962301, 2.37881218415977, 4.1464619591812, 
4.15316130101696, 4.70707172705424, 4.77267338855031, 2.03737184678255, 
3.81939314106, 3.26312377270195, 3.87684000847915, 3.72904913668145, 
4.21150941368065, 2.87482262642492, 2.41830268718988, 3.25814616479328, 
1.95974385334363, 4.14957253152334, 3.51852796766856, 3.31248236073798, 
3.93926475863266, 2.82676588308018, 2.25715273670682, 3.23877823069724, 
3.47139417367879, 3.09057442380978, 4.50079498118852, 4.84503359841119, 
3.05834404390917, 4.41167553240461, 4.55194984744145, 4.36569411888241, 
4.83039001292176, 2.93850101323729, 4.22239549435516, 4.80886282388512, 
4.94393108371142, 5.09584661299229, 5.05283820324407, 5.02319768413649, 
4.67005370266932, 2.87068065591085, 4.19209673281346, 4.82343926231588, 
3.91974901504793, 3.72904913668145, 4.25081432629887, 4.88033737221285, 
4.53751058675557, 5.09889228357165, 5.09889228357165, 2.7120126164778, 
3.20084942592193, 3.38475186086735, 2.57611729759449, 2.74406304100437, 
4.46897200885461, 3.07664762906049, 3.58227507536714, 2.64466064962826, 
4.66384481684621, 2.30962110926233, 3.91408252149265, 3.83967705403174, 
4.55910078340349, 3.21628402040912, 2.43541801827223, 4.05100906700729, 
4.22685401869853, 2.48748627144419, 3.29427230717969, 4.20248230878606, 
4.46949323821673, 4.21150941368065, 4.73359981456944, 3.47139417367879, 
3.81640051029768, 4.32499408591158, 4.53844903952499, 4.11184051977588, 
4.73359981456944, 4.50784277427558, 4.92221662489616, 5.00972596707877, 
2.76645294455757, 4.24203451863899, 3.63632959242775, 4.8438946910502, 
3.40019013262738, 4.64268935027678, 5.04028605762641, 4.59492002573633, 
3.84127256835413, 4.79892563273548, 4.41562762186783, 4.06871965116534, 
4.36969042097439, 3.98051398879079, 4.42043658523483, 3.75496657158094, 
3.29427230717969, 3.45730608585978, 5.04844935470778, 3.77878982474076, 
4.05166542652766, 3.28024670656985, 4.26078052262918, 3.72904913668145, 
3.10550475341744, 3.47139417367879, 4.41541846233588, 1.88505721037991, 
4.3767970882106, 4.35153448481756, 2.18557386001823, 4.31311576433973, 
2.6364550425402, 2.83579574924565, 4.27355104887647, 4.26316357649486, 
3.07193520904601), .Dim = c(500L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", 
"191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", 
"209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", 
"218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", 
"227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", 
"236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", 
"245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", 
"254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", 
"263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", 
"272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", 
"281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", 
"290", "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", 
"299", "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", 
"308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", 
"317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", 
"326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", 
"335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", 
"344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", 
"353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", 
"362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", 
"371", "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", 
"380", "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", "388", 
"389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", "397", 
"398", "399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", 
"407", "408", "409", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", 
"416", "417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", 
"425", "426", "427", "428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", 
"434", "435", "436", "437", "438", "439", "440", "441", "442", 
"443", "444", "445", "446", "447", "448", "449", "450", "451", 
"452", "453", "454", "455", "456", "457", "458", "459", "460", 
"461", "462", "463", "464", "465", "466", "467", "468", "469", 
"470", "471", "472", "473", "474", "475", "476", "477", "478", 
"479", "480", "481", "482", "483", "484", "485", "486", "487", 
"488", "489", "490", "491", "492", "493", "494", "495", "496", 
"497", "498", "499", "500"), NULL))
```

Comment: Without (sample) data and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it's difficult to give specific help.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks for your advice. It's added.

Comment: This seems to be a case for the concave hull: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/what-are-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions-for-concave-hull

Answer (score 2):

For a relatively simple implementation, you can try as follows:

Consider a running slice of the data, with a constant width. The width must be larger than the largest gap.

Construct the upper and lower hull of the points, using the Monotone Chain algorithm (there is no need to sort, your points are already by increasing abscissa). https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain

For the middle abscissa in the slice, estimate the two ordinates on the convex hull (by identifying the hull edges at that particular absicssa). By sweeping, this will create the desired curves. At both ends of the range, use all abscissas in the first and last half-slices.

There will be a small downward bias where the curvature is high and/or the window is large, but nobody's perfect.

[image]

The total running time will be proportional to the product of the number of points and the window width. But I guess that an incremental version can do better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a linear programming approach to this, and you might find R packages that will do linear programming for you.

Find a space of smooth curves such as splines, where a smooth curve is a linear combination of basis functions.

Now solve the linear program to minimize the sum, taken over all points, of the value at that point minus the value from a linear combination of basis functions at that point, subject to the constraint that the linear combination of basis functions must be no larger than the value at that point.